# Jquery - change CSS property (but don't add the "style" attribute to div)

Tags: jquery

i have a code like this:

```
    if ($(this).css("background-color")==="rgb(217, 217, 217)") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#999");
    }else{
        $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
    }
```

but the bg color rgb(217,217,217) is a hover BG color change effect...

when I change the bg color of my div ..... 
---> jquery is adding a "style=" ... " attribute
to my DIV,

but after that my css hover code doesnt work no more because the "style" attribute is blocking my "class" attribute...

So how can i change with jquery CSS class attributes without adding a style="" attribute directly into my DIV?

THanks for any help

this is my fiddle demo

https://jsfiddle.net/qcvcga8k/24/

please click at the name "Manuel Neuer" (1st in the list) 
and after the BG changed to grey, click again on the name.... the BG is changing again to white, BUT the hover effect is missing...

i would be so happy, if you have any hints for me ;)

Thx

Alex

Comment: Make the style a class and do `$(this).addClass('myClass');` instead of doing it with `.css(...)`

Comment: was not the goal! but I found a solution with this here:

$(this).attr('class', 'greyRow'); --------> THX for your help!

Comment: Sorry to intervene, but `$(this).attr('class', 'greyRow');` is inefficient use of jQuery, which has dedicated methods to manage class values.

Answer (score 1):

Define a CSS class for this, in the `<style>` element:

```
tr:selected { background-color: #999 }
```

Then replace your code:

```
if ($(this).css("background-color")==="rgb(217, 217, 217)") {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#999");
}else{
    $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
}
```

with this:

```
$(this).toggle('.selected');
```